# reading embeded pdf files from excel using c#

Tags: c#, pdf

I have an excel  sheet which is embeded with PDF files. Is there any way to read that embeded PDF files from excel work sheet and saving in to data base using C#.

Comment: This question is way too broad to be answered on SO. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to understand why that is.

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that u can find some classes in M[icrosoft.Office.Interop.Excel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel(v=office.15).aspx) namespace which can help to extract object embedded into Excel sheet.

for example WorksheetClass class